# Could I use boost::serialization library to serialize a union-like class of C++

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have implemented an union-like class which is learnt from C++ Primer section 19.6.

Is there any chance to serialize it by using boost::serialization library?

Comment: What do you mean by "union-*like*"? Is it a `union`-proper or something else?

Comment: @user2079303 This is the [example](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15950633/) from C++ Primer.

Comment: Put the definition of the class into the question. Including only the member variables should be enough, don't copy paste it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6d21bc9d6027964)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

using V = boost::variant<std::string, double, int>;

int main()
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    oa << std::vector<V> { 3.14, "std::string", 42 };
}
```

Prints

```
22 serialization::archive 14 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 3.14000000000000012e+00 0 11 std::string 2 42
```

Use a binary_archive or xml_archive. Suppress headers if you must. You can of course deserialize and add variant members with custom serialization.